# Matching virtual camera to real camera

Tags: math, computer-vision, augmented-reality, xna-4.0

I am trying to get a simple augmented reality app going.
I have got a rig set up that allows me to detect the rotation and position of a physical webcam. I have the webcam video being pumped in to a little 3d xna app. In the app I have the virtual camera being positioned and rotated to match the real camera.

When I overlay the 3d graphics perspective lines don't seem quite line up and when I move the physical camera the 3d graphics dont track quite right.

What parameters are involved in getting the 3d graphics to line up with the real world imagery?

Comment: This largely depends on the lens being used. If you're planning on using multiple types of cameras you may need to add some kind of calibration to your app.

Comment: The kind of calibrations I need to do is specifically what I am asking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV includes tools and a great theoretical discussion on [camera calibration models](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html), and the approaches that can be used to correct for distortions. An inverse model could be used to distort the generated 3d mesh.

Comment: Thank you.  However, I should mention that while helpful, I am not really all that interested in correcting for lens distortion, I just want get the general perspective lines and such right

Comment: @Mr Bell: The first sentence on the linked page says *"The functions in this section use the so-called pinhole camera model"*. The pinhole camera model is just about "getting perspective right", it doesn't have lens distortion (there's no lens in a pinhole camera)